# actualizar un campo en función de si cumple o no un campo de otra tabla otra tabla

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

A ver si podeis ayudarme con este tema. Tengo una tabla "formaciones" en las que se registran las formaciones que reciben los trabajadores, dentro de esta tabla hay un campo que va ligado a otra tabla (1-n) ya que en una misma formacion puede haber varios trabajadores.
A parte de pasar los datos al controlador para guardar la formacion me gustaria que si en función del campo "tipo de formacion" es igual a un valor actualice un campo de la tabla trabajador del listado que han participado con la fecha de la formacion que estoy registrando inicialmente.
Paso código a ver si podeis darme una pista ya que no se como guardar los datos en cada uno de los trabajadores que han participado.

Vereis en el script que el ultimo else es el que quiero que actualice.

````
                                    $('#btn_guardar_formacion').click(function() {
                                            var nroformacion = '<?php echo $contador_formaciones ?>';
                                            var tipo_fr = $('#tipo_fr').val();
                                            var fecha_fr = $('#fecha_fr').val();
                                            var fechacad_fr = $('#fechacad_fr').val();
                                            var formador_fr = $('#formador_fr').val();


                                            if (fecha_fr == "") {
                                                alert("debe indicar la fecha de formacion");

                                            } else if (nroformacion == "") {
                                                alert("debe indicar el numero de formacion");

                                            } else if {
                                                var url = "../../app/controllers/formaciones/registrar_formacion.php";
                                                $.get(url, {
                                                    nroformacion: nroformacion,
                                                    tipo_fr: tipo_fr,
                                                    fecha_fr: fecha_fr,
                                                    fechacad_fr: fechacad_fr,
                                                    formador_fr: formador_fr
                                                }, function(datos) {
                                                    $('#respuesta_registro_formacion').html(datos);
                                                })
                                            } else($tipo_fr == 1) {
                                                <?php
                                                 $sentencia2 = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE trabajadores as tr SET tr.formacionpdt_tr = $fecha_tr 
                                                INNER JOIN form_asistencia as fas ON tr.id_trabajador = fas.idtrabajador_fas
                                                INNER JOIN formacion as fr ON fas.nroformacion = fr.nroformacion WHERE tr.id_trabajador = fas.idtrabajador_fas");
                                                $sentencia2 -> bindParam('formacionpdt_tr', $fecha_fr);
                                                ?>
                                            }

                                        }

                                    );
                                </script>```

[![Tablas de relaciones][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8LAG.png
````

Comment: No se si seria interesante hacer un trigger o algo similar ya que no se como proceder

Comment: No sé si entendí bien.  ¿La fecha de la formación cambia y quieres actualizar ese dato en `trabajadores`? Lo propio sería poner el ID de la formación en `trabajadores`, no la fecha. Y, parecería más bien un tipo de relación muchos a muchos, en cuyo caso necesitarás una tercera tabla que asocie trabajador y formación.

Comment: Mas o menos si es lo que comentas, pero te detallo: un trabajador puede recibir varios tipos de formación, solo hay un tipo de formacion que en caso de que un trabajador la vuelva a recibir debe actualizar el campo concreto "formacionpdt" que he puesto (al final es para decir que fecha tiene la ultima formacionpdt del trabajador). es verdad que podria probar con una tabla intermedia y hacer la consulta desde la propia tabla de trabajadores. El problema que veo es como actualizo dicho campo.

Comment: No entendí mucho tu comentario. Sospecho que estás queriendo reflejar en el lugar equivocado una lógica que debería ir en otras tablas. Y no me refiero sólo a una tercera tabla que asocie `trabajador` y `formacion`, sino también a lo que dices de la fecha. ¿Por qué no tener en una tabla las fechas en que son asignadas las formaciones o algo así y consultar esa tabla para saber la última fecha, la formación más reciente, o la más vieja, o las formaciones del mes de enero del año 2018, etc, etc, etc. No sé si me explico. No deberías forzar a una tabla para meter con calzador una lógica en ella.

Comment: Más bien, lo que deberías es diseñar un modelo de datos flexible, que refleje tus reglas de negocio y que se adapte a cualquier cambio, permitiendo además cualquier tipo de consulta y en el que no haya redundancia de datos. Desde que uno ve un constante intento de actualización de tablas de entidad, como es `trabajador`, rápidamente piensa que hay un grave error en ese modelo de datos, porque **ese tipo de tablas no deberían cambiar tanto**. Una tabla de ese tipo cambia solamente en casos muy puntuales, como que el trabajador tiene otro hijo, o fue ascendido de puesto o cosas así.

Comment: *que en caso de que un trabajador la vuelva a recibir debe actualizar el campo concreto "formacionpdt" que he puesto (al final es para decir que fecha tiene la ultima formacionpdt del trabajador).*  ... *El problema que veo es como actualizo dicho campo.*  ... En la tabla `trabajador_formacion`, que sería la tabla asociativa, podrías tener los campos: `id_formacion, id_trabajador, inicio, fin` y ya tienes el problema resuelto. Cuando hablaba de flexibilidad, y de adaptarse a cualquier requerimiento, me refería a que mañana te pueden pedir un informe del tipo ...

Comment: ... "Búscame el total de formaciones del trabajador fulano en el año tal", o "Búscame el total de formaciones que duraron más de tantos días en los meses tal y tal entre el año tal y tal", etc, etc. Dado que tienes en la tabla asociativa una fecha de inicio y de fin, puedes hacer ese cálculo sin ningún problema y sin redundancia de datos. He puesto unos ejemplos más extremos de la simplicidad que pareces requerir ahora y que puedes resolver también fácilmente con un modelo de datos como este o parecido.

Comment: El problema, creo yo, es que tú intentas actualizar la tabla `trabajador`, cuando lo que debería ocurrir es **una nueva inserción** en la tabla `trabajador_formacion`, con la nueva formación y la nueva fecha de inicio y de fin de dicha formación. Esto no solamente evitará que estés actualizando constantemente una tabla de entidad, sino que te permitirá guardar un historial de las formaciones de ese trabajador, y de las formaciones en sí mismas, para generar futuros informes complejos que te puedan pedir, como los ejemplos mencionados en mi anterior comentario. No sé si me doy a entender.

Comment: A. Cedano, muchas gracias, me has clarificado un poco todo. Optare por lo comentado, añadir una tabla nueva de trabajador-formacion para hacer consultas mas concretas. Le voy a dar unas cuantas vueltas a ver como pinta, sino volvemos por aqui.

Comment: y donde esta el codigo php ??? cuando hablamos de tablas (backend) y se usa la etiqueta php ... es por que hay algun problema con el codigo php ... pero no lo encuentro  ...

Comment: tambien veo que el codigo javascript tiene errores ... } else if { y la clausuda del if???

Comment: no hay manera que tu codigo se ejecute... tiene errores de sintaxis detectables a simple vista.

Comment: gracias francisco, no se si es posible creo que si pero el codigo php de esta consulta lo tiro dentro del ultimo else

Comment: no es eso lo que te he preguntado ... hay errores de sintaxis que no permiten nisiquiera ejecutar el codigo, edita tu pregunta y coloca el codigo minimo funcional para poder analisarlo. lo que pussiste en la pregunta no dice nada... ni se puede usar